# Какого года или с какого года?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто на вопрос о годе рождения я слышу ответ: "я С такого-то года". Причем, слышал его как в жизни, так и в кино. Разве это правильно? Мне всегда казалось, что С тут совсем не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, неправильно. Предлог "с" здесь совсем неуместен, ведь полная фраза звучит так: "Я такого-то года рождения" в ответ на вопрос: "Каков Ваш год рождения?" или "Какого Вы года рождения?"

Answer (score -1):

Ерунда! В жизни не слышал вопроса "Каков Ваш год рождения?" или ""Какого Вы года рождения?"". Спрашивают или "Год рождения?"или "С какого ты года?". Соответственно и ответы. Аще нада бы спрашивать : "Те скока лет-та?" Проблема в том, что вопрошаемый может не уметь считать, но может помнить год рождения. Потому "Ты с какого года?" соответствует требованиям, ибо на вопрос "Год рождения?" можно получить встречный вопрос "Чей?". К моему удивлению узнал, что многие украинцы не понимают вопроса "С какого ты года", хотя фраза "А ти з якого року?" у них встречается.

Comment: Какого парень года? \\ С какого парохода? \\ И на каких морях\\ Ты побывал моряк?

Comment: Уверен, что вопрос "с какого года" ненормативен. Это примерно как "с какого года Вы больны?", "с какого года Вы ушли с работы?" Привязать к нему год рождения сложно